# Objective-C send get method with header to download file

Tags: objective-c, download, get, header

in my osx app, I want to download a file from a website, in order to do that, I first tried with `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url` but I'm accessing ot throught an API, so I need to send a token in the header of my GET request so now, my method to download a file is that:

```
-(void)downloadFile:(NSString*)name from:(NSString*)stringURL in:(NSString*)path{
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:self.token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSLog(@"%@", stringURL);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    if ( data )
    {
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.torrent", path,name];
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

The url loged is the good one. But the data variable is nil and the error one contain an NSURLErrorDomaincode with the code 1002. Referring to the doc:

> Returned when a properly formed URL cannot be handled by the framework.
>   The most likely cause is that there is no available protocol handler for the URL.

So how can I send a GET request with custom headers and then download the file ?

Comment: What's the actual URL?

Comment: [this](http://api.t411.io/torrents/download/4693572) is the URL I try to download. And [this](http://api.t411.io/) is the API documentation, but you need an account to test it. Ask me for my credential if you want to test it as it's just test credential or you need to create the account [here](http://t411.io).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

1. `documentsDirectory` is not used, so the data can be wrote to nowhere.
2. The default HTTP method is **GET** so you do not need to specify it.
3. You should pass in the full URL: *http://api.t411.io/torrents/download/4693572*. And I thought you may passed in *api.t411.io/torrents/download/4693572* before.

And I recommend you using the `NSURLSession` API that Apple brings in iOS 7 and OS X v10.9.

```
// in viewDidLoad
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  _config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": self.token};
  _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:_config];
}

- (void)downloadFile:(NSString*)name from:(NSString*)stringURL in:(NSString*)path {
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

  NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [_session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
      return;
    }

    if (data) {

      // Your file writing code here
      NSLog(@"%@", data);
    }
  }];

  [task resume];
}
```

Comment: Yes, path and documentDirectory was copy pasted from an example, so they were useless as I pass the path in parameters. And thank you for NSURLSession it works fine, and I even think about using it in my whole project. Thanks ;)